# CIFS/SMB vs HTTP/RTSP streaming to share video files

Tags: http, video-streaming, rtsp, cifs, audiovideoplayback

I was designing a video management system for multiple clients where the recording server is supposed to record video clips to its local drive and then whenever the client wants to playback these recorded videos, it should be shared with the client. There seem to be two approaches to this:

1. Use windows file sharing protocol like SMB/CIFS to share the drive to all the clients - windows permits up-to 20 clients, once the drive is shared it will be mapped by every client as a local drive and client can view whichever file is to be played back
2. Use a streaming server and based on client requests, stream (HTTP/RTSP streaming) a particular file that is required by a client (separate thread to listen and stream required files to each client), in this case server management would become tedious as the number of clients increase

Can anyone let me know the pros and cons of each of these approaches, so that I can design an efficient architecture for the same? Most video management software I have seen, seem to be using the second approach, any specific advantages in doing that?

Regards,
Saurabh Gandhi